# Skip particular action filter from multiple filters on controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Is it good practice to use more than one action filters(IAsyncActionFilter) on top of one action method like below? since these filters can be reused separately too in other places, I can't combine ShippingAuthorizationFilter & OrderAuthorizationFilter validation logics under one filter.

```
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(ShippingAuthorizationFilter))]
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(OrderAuthorizationFilter))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> TestUser()
    {
        return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

On 'ShippingAuthorizationFilter', if await next(); is called, it calls next filter in the order i.e., 'OrderAuthorizationFilter' which meets the requirement, but on certain condition want to skip 'OrderAuthorizationFilter' execution but want to execute "TestUser" action method right after "ShippingAuthorizationFilter" action filter execution. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to use multiple filters on one Action. In fact MVC filters like `HttpGet, Authorize, OutputCache` etc. comes as separate filters.

Separation of concern is also a good practice - i.e. one filter should do one particular job. There are sequence of executions. You should maintain the sequence for performance. i.e. most obvious ones should run first.

**Update:**

You should let the filters execute and based on some logic filters can be stopped from taking actions. Like have a shared data between the filters:

For example in your `ShippingAuthorizationFilter` filter if you put a data in an Item like this:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Items["orderAuthorized"] = True;
```

Then in the `OrderAuthorizationFilter` filter check the value of `filterContext.HttpContext.Items["orderAuthorized"]` and decide if the `OrderAuthorizationFilter` filter should process its logic or skip. Which would then execute your `TestUser` action.

The Item data would be cleared out at the end of the request.

Comment: HttpGet, Authorize are not filters but Attributes right? Also in multiple filters scenario how how to skip the very next filter execution only on certain condition and to execute action method right away?

Comment: @191180rk yes the correct term would be Attribute. However the `Authorize` attribute corresponds to an `AuthorizationFilter` that implements the `IAuthorizationFilter` interface.

Comment: In multiple filters scenario how how to skip the very next filter execution only on certain condition and to execute action method right away?

Comment: @191180rk I have added some more updates to the answer. Does that help?

Comment: There are few more ways will try to post those soon. But to me that is the cleaner and non-complex way.

Comment: @ Rahatur the above workaround introduce code complexity, which means "ShippingAuthorizationFilter" should be followed by "OrderAuthorizationFilter", the ORDER of the filters should be maintained otherwise above workaround wont work. But I am looking for generic solution.